# How to jquery input array with auto decimal (each)

Tags: jquery, arrays, forms, decimal

I have some input box fields loop from database records counts look like this..

```
<input name="price[]" id="price_1" />
<input name="price[]" id="price_2" />
<input name="price[]" id="price_3" />
```

And I also have a javascript for automatic decimal look like this...
(This script will auto fill 2 decimal 0.00 into the value.

```
function autoDecimal(el){
$(el).blur(function(){
    var myNumeric = parseFloat($(this).val());
    if (!myNumeric) {
        $(this).val('0.00');
    } else {
        $(this).val(myNumeric.toFixed(2));
    }
});
}
```

This script work perfectly only 1 element id like

```
autoDecimal('#a');
```

but I need to improve it to check all input box with array names.
like this or somthing better than this code below.

```
$('input['price']).each(function(){
// do auto matic add decimal each input box
});
```

If you have an idea please share.

Thanks (I'm not advanced in javascript or jquery)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input[name~="price"]').blur(function(){
    var myNumeric = parseFloat($(this).val());
    if (!myNumeric) 
    {
        $(this).val('0.00');
    } 
    else 
    {
        $(this).val(myNumeric.toFixed(2));
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your idea but I don't understand why I can use this value ~=. It won't happen anything in my script or maybe because I use jquery 1.7.2?

Comment: Using ~= in your selector finds all input fields which have the text "price" in their name

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/azqEp/)**

```
$("input:text").on("keyup", function(e) {
    var myNumeric = parseFloat($(this).val());
    if (!myNumeric) 
    {
        $(this).val('0.00');
    } 
    else 
    {
        $(this).val(myNumeric.toFixed(2));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reuse the function 'autodecimal' but simply pass to it a right jquery selector like the one suggested by slash197 :

```
autoDecimal('input[name~="price"]');
```

This should work.